# Choose between makefile and Makefile on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I want to do a make in a directory with both Makefile and makefile. By default, it will execute makefile. Is there any options I can do to execute the Makefile instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the sane reason to have both `Makefile` & `makefile` ? This looks awful!

Comment: Use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) and out-of-source build.

Comment: Hmm I made makefile by myself and just wanted to add some personal configuration to it. And use it to call default Makefile

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easy option is to use `-f`:

```
$ make -f Makefile
```

From `man 1 make` (the GNU make, I presume):

> If no `-f` option is present, make will look for the makefiles `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order.

So you con link your Makefile to the name GNUmakefile. But my advise, if you really want this, is to use an alias:

```
$ alias make='make -f Makefile'
```

Answer (score 3):

Read [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) documentation. Just type

```
 make -f Makefile
```

You might consider making a symlink from `Makefile` to `GNUmakefile` but I consider horrible to have several *makefile* like files.

Having both `Makefile` and `makefile` makes your project unreadable. Please have mercy on your successor developer.