# How to create a makefile in gcc

Tags: c, windows, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile but facing some issues.
I installed gcc compiler in Windows 7, then created one simple helloworld example. After that compiled that C file using the following command:

```
gcc filename.c
```

After this I am getting an exe file. I am calling this project in some tool for that, tool required makefie.

As I understood makefile is a text file, which tells or consist some commands how to build, run and clean the project.

So according to this I am writing a makefile:

```
CC=gcc

SRCS=src/hello.c

.PHONY: all
all: clean build
    @echo ========== Complete ==========

.PHONY: build
build: 
    @echo ========== Build ==========
    $(CC) hello.c

.PHONY: run
run: 
    @echo ========== Run ==========
    make

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo ========== Clean ==========
    rm hello.exe

./obj:
    mkdir ./obj
```

While calling this simple project in tool, getting error
"no rule to make target clean"

Please tell me which steps I followed those are correct for creation of makefile or not, and what mistake I am doing? How to create a makefile?

Comment: Why do you use DOS? It is an obsolete operating system! Can't you install [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop? You could use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to create your `Makefile` (for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)...). With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), please compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your executable

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537265/choose-between-makefile-and-makefile-on-linux/21537332) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025766/makefile-auto-dependency-generation/8025816) answers.

Comment: Are you really using DOS?

Comment: Thank you very much for the replay, please clear me,we can't create makefile in windows 7?we need to use debin or linux only?

Comment: Are both files in the same folder? Is makefile in the right folder for the tool you are using?

Comment: Of course it is possible to use the tool "make" with a makefile to build executables on Windows. (BTW, you are still using Windows 7? For your own safety, please use an up-to-date OS.) -- Your example works for me (GCC, Win10), except that "rm" is not a Windows command. Please [edit] your question and show us how you call make and the resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have not got the essence of make(1):

- Make stores in the makefiles a set of dependency rules (dependencies between files) in your build directory in order to build your project.
- There are dependency lines, and build lines, the dependencies start in column 0 of the line, while the buid lines start with a tab char.
- the rule lines have two parts, the file **that is to be built**,  a colon (`:`), and the list of files it depends on (so that if one or more of these files is modified, the rule is applied)
- If the rule has to be applied, then the set of build lines below the rule (until the next rule or a variable definition rule if found) is executed in order to build the file.

#### Example

Your file `hello.c` will be compiled into `hello.s` to create an assembler file, and then the assembly code is assembled to generate an object code `hello.o`.  Finally, this file is linked to generate the file `hello` (or `hello.exe`, if you are in windows).

You arrange your makefile to generate all the files, in a way that if you modify e.g. the assembler file `hello.s`, only the assembler pass, and the linker pass is done, but not the compiling phase that should overwrite the assembler file before assembling.  This can be done with this Makefile:

```
# this is the linking phase.  The first rule in the file is the
# default target rule, so by default, executing make will try this
# rule (but only if hello.exe was modified before hello.o)

hello.exe: hello.o
    gcc -o hello.exe hello.o

# Now, the assembling phase.  The hello.o file depends on the
# hello.s assembly code, so to assemble it we call the assembler

hello.o: hello.s
    as -o hello.o hello.s

# now, we specify the dependency from the hello.s assembler file
# from the hello.c source code file.

hello.s: hello.c
    gcc -c -S -o hello.s hello.c
```

Now, if it is the first time you execute make and you have only the file `hello.c` (and  `Makefile` of course) the make program will generate the following sequence of commands:

```
$ make
gcc -c -S -o hello.s hello.c
as -o hello.o hello.s
gcc -o hello.exe hello.o
$ _
```

but if you later modify the file `hello.s` (I will `touch(1)` it, to change its modification date:

```
$ touch hello.s
$ make
as -o hello.o hello.s
gcc -o hello.exe hello.o
$ _
```

but if you touch `hello.c`, everything will be made again:

```
$ touch hello.c
$ make
gcc -c -S -o hello.s hello.c
as -o hello.o hello.s
gcc -o hello.exe hello.o
$ _
```

Make builds a dependency graph and follows it in order to build the target you have specified in the command line, so if you use make with a target, it will stop as soon as the target is built:

```
$ make hello.o
gcc -c -S -o hello.s hello.c
as -o hello.o hello.s
$ _
```

I recommend you to read a book on make.  A good one is the GNU Make documentation that is online on your system as an info file: just execute:

```
$ info make
```

(and `info` will open a text screen to allow you to read the full documentation of `make`)